# Error in connecting to docker container from sql-client of Host network

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am triggering mysql with compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-sql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: my-sql
    ports:
     - 3306:3306
    environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: passw0rd 
     MYSQL_USER: dbuser
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass1234
     MYSQL_DATABASE: connect_test
```

On find IPAdress of container in following manner:

```
root@sevenos:~# docker inspect my-sql | grep IPAddress
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
```

When i am connecting with `my-sql client` outside the container,I am getting error as follows:

```
root@sevenos:~# mysql -uroot -ppassw0rd -h 172.18.0.2 -P 3306
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be 
loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

You can init docker with the command to load default authentication plugin as follow:

```
mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes_from:
        - mysql-data
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
```

And before you run it you must remove all mysql volumes:

```
docker-compose rm
docker volume rm list_of_your_volumes
docker-compose up
```

You can take a look at for more details: https://github.com/passbolt/passbolt_docker/issues/103